# What class of object would a serialized ajax form be translated to in an action aparameter of a Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, serialization, spring-mvc, types

If a HTML form contains multiple input fields:

```
 <form>
 <input id="in1" type="text" value="one">
 <input id="in2" type="text" value="two">
 <input id="in3" type="text" value="three">
 </form>
```

and is passed to a Spring controller as a serialized form like this:

```
new Ajax.Request('/doajax', 
{asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, 
parameters: $('ajax_form').serialize(true)});
```

what Java type would be needed to read the serialized `ajax_form` in a Spring 3 controller?

```
@RequestMapping("/doajax")
@ResponseBody
public String doAjax(@RequestParam <?Type> ajaxForm 
{
 // do something
}
```

Comment: what does the string `$('ajax_form').serialize(true)` look like?

Comment: I can't tell what the String looks like because I tried making it "@RequestParam String ajaxForm" but I got an error saying no such required parameter exists when I posted the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you use form fields without `name`s, so `serialize()` actually produces an empty result. Add names:

```
<form> 
 <input name = "in1" id="in1" type="text" value="one"> 
 <input name = "in2" id="in2" type="text" value="two"> 
 <input name = "in3" id="in3" type="text" value="three"> 
</form>
```

I guess you use Prototype, so `parameters: $('ajax_form').serialize(true)` produces a URL-encoded representation of the form (and also you don't need `true` here, it adds unnecessary conversion). Since `@RequestParam` can't bind complex types, you can bind  fields as separate parameters:

```
public String doAjax(@RequestParam("in1") String in1, 
    @RequestParam("in2") String in2, @RequestParam("in2") String in2)
```

Also you can create a class to hold form data and pass it as a model attribute:

```
public class AjaxForm {
    private String in1;
    private String in2;
    private String in3;

    ... getters, setters ...
}
```

-

```
public String doAjax(AjaxForm form)
```

Comment: The @RequestParams work but the AjaxForm is not working. It doesn't seem to know how to map the form fields to the class.

Comment: @Bowe: It should work. Make sure that names of the class properties match the names of the form fields, and that the class have properly named getters and setters.

Comment: Some of the form fields have underscores. So the HTML form field is called "order_id" but the class field is called "orderId". Is there any way to associate these without renaming the HTML? With @RequestParam, you can do this by saying: @RequestParam(value="order_id") String orderId

Comment: I've posted a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646314/with-a-form-class-in-spring-3-how-do-you-map-a-html-form-field-called-order-id